# Using Foundation Accordian and Tabs in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, zurb-foundation

I am working on a project that uses AngularJS. For the CSS side of the ball, I'm relying on Zurb Foundation 5. For the most part, I have things working, with two exceptions: [accordians](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/accordion.html) and [tabs](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/tabs.html).

Whenever I use these items, they initially render just fine. However, whenever I try to change tabs or panels, I get a JavaScript error. The error comes from foundation.min.js and says:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'active_class' of undefined

How do I get this resolved so that I can use these two controls within the context of AngularJS?

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but in Ember.js. Did you ever find a fix?

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue on Rails 4 due to the newly implemented turbolinks. For anyone who has that issue, it can be solved with the method in the top answer here: [Rails 4: how to use $(document).ready() with turbo-links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770517/rails-4-how-to-use-document-ready-with-turbo-links).

My guess is that since the links are being loaded asynchronously, Foundation.js doesn't have a chance to attach the proper handlers to those elements.

Answer (score 0):

My bet is that your accordion and tabs are being shown by conditional with an `ng-if` and they aren't being rendered in time for foundation to attach its handlers. I fixed my issue by changing `ng-if` to `ng-show`